# How to copy information across excel workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have 5 different files (all in the same folder), one of them I use it as a Master/Reporting Workbook the others are where agents fill information, in the master file I have several sheets I want to paste the info in a sheet called Consolidated, all the other files have just 1 sheet (Sheet1) and the range to copy the info from is the same (A2:AP1779).

I'm trying an approach such as (Please do mind the comments)

```
Sub cnsldt()Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim lCell as Range


    FilePath = "Z:\Lead Generation\Jose Buitrago\Special Projects-Asignments\Data Gap Project\"
    FileName = "Data Gap Project High Priority 2016 - "
    iRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

'First we clear the sheet where I'm going to paste the info
Set lCell = Sheets("Consolidated").Cell(iRow,AP)
Range("A2",lCell).ClearContents

'not sure if must open files or just copy the info
'not sure if should unhide Column A
'AgentTest not declared because that is the name of the file so in this example the target is Z:\Lead Generation\Jose Buitrago\Special Projects-Asignments\Data Gap Project\Data Gap Project High Priority 2016 - AgentTest.xslx

Workbooks("FilePath & FileName & AgentTest.xslx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:AP1779").Copy
Workbooks("FilePath & Data Gap Project High Priority 2016.xslx").Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesApplication.CutCopyMode = False

'How should I proceed afterwards since the paste range its not A2 it would be Cell(iRow+1,A) ?



End Sub
```

I have many doubts on how to tackle this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below

```
Workbooks(FilePath & "Data Gap Project High Priority 2016.xslx").Sheets("Consolidated").Range ("A" & iRow + 1)
```

**EDIT 1**

Not Tested. But try with below code.

```
Sub cnsldt()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim lCell As Range
    FilePath = "Z:\Lead Generation\Jose Buitrago\Special Projects-Asignments\Data Gap Project\"
    FileName = "Data Gap Project High Priority 2016 - "
    Workbooks.Open (FilePath & FileName & "AgentTest.xslx")
    iRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    'First we clear the sheet where I'm going to paste the info
    Set lCell = Sheets("Consolidated").Cell(iRow, AP)
    Range("A2", lCell).ClearContents
    'not sure if must open files or just copy the info
    'not sure if should unhide Column A
    'AgentTest not declared because that is the name of the file so in this example the target is Z:\Lead Generation\Jose Buitrago\Special Projects-Asignments\Data Gap Project\Data Gap Project High Priority 2016 - AgentTest.xslx
    Workbooks(FilePath & FileName & "AgentTest.xslx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:AP1779").Copy
    Workbooks(FilePath & "Data Gap Project High Priority 2016.xslx").Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesApplication.CutCopyMode = False
    Workbooks(FilePath & "Data Gap Project High Priority 2016.xslx").Sheets("Consolidated").Range ("A" & iRow + 1)
    'How should I proceed afterwards since the paste range its not A2 it would be Cell(iRow+1,A) ????
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do I need this `Workbooks.Open (FilePath & FileName)`

Comment: You need this to open the file. `Workbooks.Open (FilePath & FileName & "AgentTest.xslx")`

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Close`. If you don't want to save the file  then it must be `ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)`